# How Does One Replace an Import with a variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My question may sound confusing, and frankly it does. What I am attempting to make is a component to use later on multiple different locations. The component is a card with an icon, some text and a button. What I have in the dictionary are all possible icons I will be using for this project. What I don't have is the knowledge of how to do this. I am trying to implement the "DRY" principal, hence why I seek to do it this way. I would like a card which can be imported then have some variables that will add the icon, text and button.

Here is my code below.

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "../Button/Button";
import { IoAppsSharp } from "react-icons/io5";
import { ImDisplay } from "react-icons/im";
import { AiFillSignal } from "react-icons/ai";
import { MdPhoneInTalk } from "react-icons/md";
import { GrCode } from "react-icons/gr";
import { MdSecurity } from "react-icons/md";
import { IoMdSchool } from "react-icons/io";

const iconDict = {
    iconOne: <IoAppsSharp />,
    iconTwo: <ImDisplay />,
    iconThree: <AiFillSignal />,
    iconFour: <MdPhoneInTalk />,
    iconFive: <GrCode />,
    iconSix: <MdSecurity />,
    iconSeven: <IoMdSchool />
}


const Card = ({ icon, title, text, button }) => {
    const checkIcon = iconDict.includes(icon) ? icon : iconDict.iconOne;



    return (
        <a
            href="Bespoke Software"
            className="card"
        >
            <div className="card__icon-container">
                <IoAppsSharp className="card__icon-container--icon" />
            </div>

            <div className="card__text-container">
                <h2>Bespoke Software</h2>
                <p>
                    Tailored software solutions to improve business productivity and
                    online profits.
                </p>
                <br />
            </div>
            <div className="card__button-container">
                <Button>Read More</Button>
            </div>
        </a>
    );
}

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re your title:

> How Does One Replace an Import with a variable?

You can't parameterize modules like that, but the good news is you don't have to to solve your problem. :-)

Instead, we can solve it like this: Make `Card`, itself, directly accept the icon, not the *name* of the icon, and then (optionally) use a [Higher-Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#use-hocs-for-cross-cutting-concerns) (HOC) to create a version of `Card` that accepts names instead (using a given dictionary).

The new `Card`:

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "../Button/Button";

const Card = ({ checkIcon, title, text, button }) => {
    return (
        <a href="Bespoke Software" className="card">
            <div className="card__icon-container">
                <IoAppsSharp className="card__icon-container--icon" />
            </div>

            <div className="card__text-container">
                <h2>Bespoke Software</h2>
                <p>
                    Tailored software solutions to improve business productivity and online profits.
                </p>
                <br />
            </div>
            <div className="card__button-container">
                <Button>Read More</Button>
            </div>
        </a>
    );
};
```

Using `Card` directly:

```
<Card checkIcon={<IoAppsSharp/>} {/*...*/} />
// Or keep using `iconDict`:
<Card checkIcon={iconDict.iconOne} {/*...*/} />
```

The optional HOC:

```
function withIcons(Card, iconDict) {
    return ({icon, ...rest}) => {
        const checkIcon = iconDict.includes(icon) ? icon : iconDict.default; // Note I changed the name of the default
        return <Card checkIcon={checkIcon} {...rest} />;
    };
}
```

Using the HOC:

```
const iconDict = {
    iconOne: <IoAppsSharp />,
    iconTwo: <ImDisplay />,
    iconThree: <AiFillSignal />,
    iconFour: <MdPhoneInTalk />,
    iconFive: <GrCode />,
    iconSix: <MdSecurity />,
    iconSeven: <IoMdSchool />,
};
const CardWithCertainIcons = withIcons(Card, iconDict);
```

Using that component:

```
<CardWithCertainIcons icon="iconOne" {/*...*/ />
```

If doing the HOC, see the [link earlier](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#use-hocs-for-cross-cutting-concerns) for some important information about them re refs and static methods and such.